# Using templates and Create conflicts for creating a Person Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Person Model

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
 
   public string Gender { get; set; }

   public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a PersonTemplate Model

```
public class PersonTemplate
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
 
   public string Gender { get; set; }

   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have two PersonTemplate with these values:

```
var personTemplateOne = new PersonTemplate {
 Name = "",
 Gender = "Male",
 Age = 18
};

var personTemplateTwo = new PersonTemplate {
 Name = "",
 Gender = "Female",
 Age = 16
}
```

I wanted to use the two PersonTemplate that I created and apply it to

```
var person = new Person();
```

The two templates has a value for the Gender and Age property. I wanted to output that there's a conflict between the two templates and let the user select which template it will use on each field. What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hello the best approach is the reflection method.
But also you can create a function compare with two objects as parameters and compare their properties with output the list with conflicts.

function list compare( PersonTemplate p1, PersonTemolate p2)
{
GetProperties with foreach and then getvalues from p1 and p2 .

If are same no problem , if not add the conflict in the list ...

}

But I found a ready solution that can help you with reflection : [Getting Difference Between Two Objects With Same Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432086/getting-difference-between-two-objects-with-same-properties/26432504)

Also you have to change you
class Person => class Person : PersonTemplate
and class person now will have only the id property. So now you can insert a PersonTemplate class in Person

Comment: I will try your suggestion and comeback if anything comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but it does sound like you want to use inheritance. Perhaps...

```
public class Person : PersonTemplate
```

Also, you have Age declared as a string and you are passing an int value to it.